# Ngrx: populate success dispatched actions on component

Tags: ngrx

I'm dispatching an `ADD_SOURCE` action from my component that when it success dispatches another `ADD_SOURCE_SUCCESS`:

```
this.store$
  .select(fromRoot.getUserState)
  .filter(user => user.id != null && user.logged)
  .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
  .do(user => this.store$.dispatch({type: 'ADD_SOURCE', payload: user.username}))
  .subscribe();
```

This is the effect that returns the `ADD_SOURCE_SUCCESS` according to a net call:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: true })
  addSource$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType('ADD_SOURCE')
    .switchMap(
      (action: Action) =>
        this.userService.addCard(action.payload.username, action.payload.token)
          .map((card: CardDTO) => {
            return <Action>{
              type: 'ADD_SOURCE_SUCCESS',
              payload: <ICard>{ ... }
            };
          })
          .catch(_ => {
            return Observable.of(<Action>{ type: 'ADD_SOURCE_FAILED', payload: { }});
          }));
```

So, then a new `ADD_SOURCE_SUCCESS` is dispatched on my reducer:

```
private static saveSourceSuccess(sourcesRdx, type, payload) {
    return <ISourceRedux>{
        ids: [ ...sourcesRdx.ids, payload.id ],
        entities: Object.assign({}, sourcesRdx.entities, {[payload.id]: payload}),
        selectedIds: sourcesRdx.selectedIds,
        editingSource: null
    };
}
```

Nevertheless, I don't quite figure out how to say on my component that the operation has been success and do one thing or another one...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in your reducer, you should also handle the success & fail errors, set the store with an error message or whatever you need as data, and make a selector on it. Then the ui should subscribe to this new selector and you ll be notified
check this chapter
[selectors](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510#projecting-data)